# How to collapse levels of a factor based on count?

Tags: r

I have a variable with 40 levels and I want to collapse all levels that have a count of less than 500 into a new level called 'Other'

I played around with the group_category function, but I'm still a novice in R, so I couldn't figure it out quite yet.

**Sample Data:**

Group 1 n=21,000

Group 2 n = 1,000

Group 3 n = 499

Group 4 n = 1

**Expected Output:**

Group 1 n = 21,000

Group 2 n = 1,000

Other n =500

Comment: See `forcats::fct_lump` https://forcats.tidyverse.org/reference/fct_lump.html

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need, but for some reason the 'min' argument isn't working. I see a fct_lump_min function in the link above, but it doesn't seem to be popping up for me.

Comment: It works fine for me `x <- c(rep(1,210),rep(2,100),rep(3,49),rep(4,1));x<-factor(x);fct_lump_min(x, min = 50)`. Note I use `forcats0.4.0`

Comment: Thanks! Had to update to 0.4.0 and now it pops up.

Answer (score 0):

To use a base `R` solution:

```
## sample to mix up the vector a bit
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(factor(rep(1:4, c(21000, 1000, 499, 1))))

## count occurence of levels
tab <- c(table(x))
## lookup table, where...
lkp <- setNames(names(tab), names(tab))
## elements with count <500 are labelled "other"
lkp[tab < 500] <- "other"
## create new factor with proper labels
y <- factor(lkp[as.character(x)])
## check the result
table(x, y)
## Recoding worked
#    y
# x       1     2 other
#   1 21000     0     0
#   2     0  1000     0
#   3     0     0   499
#   4     0     0     1
```